# is there any way that sub-directory of a domain and its sub-domain work exactly the same way?

Tags: domain, subdomain

For example, I have a domain example.com. Then I have created a subdomain from it e.g same.example.com

I want that, same.example.com and example.com/same/ will work the same way. such as same.example.com/another/ and example.com/same/another will make the same result and so will do any other HTTP request and any further sub-directories.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this, and probably the one that will be easiest to maintain long-term, is to have your web server redirect one method to the other.

This is the approach that Google uses. For example, browsing to:

```
https://maps.google.com/
```

automatically redirects the user to:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your web root for `example.com` was a folder called ex. `www\html`, you could create a folder called ex. `www\html\same` and point `same.example.com` to it (i.e. make `www\html\same` the webroot for your subdomain). Then `example.com\same` and `same.example.com` would yield the same content.

With this method, if you added another folder e.g. `www\html\same\another`, then `example.com\same\another` and `same.example.com\another` would automatically (again) yield the same content.